# How could I create sum of column itself dynamically in python

Tags: python, dataframe, dynamic, sum, average

My raw data is:

```
def f_ST(ST,F,T):
    a=ST/F-1-np.log(ST/F)
    return 2*a/T

df=pd.DataFrame(range(50,140,5),columns=['K'])
df['f(K0)']=df.apply(lambda x: f_ST(x.K,100,0.25),axis=1)
df['f(K1)']=df['f(K0)'].shift(-1)
df['dK']=df['K'].diff(1)
```

The thing I want to do is: I have a funtion f(k)

```
f(k)= (k-100)/100 - ln(k/100)
```

I want to calculate w, which goes following the steps

1. get 1-period foward value of f(k), then calculate

```
tmp(k)=f1_f(k)-f(k)/dk
```

2. w is calculated as

```
w[0]=tmpw[0]

w[n]-tmpw[n]-(w[0]+w[1]+...w[n-1])
```

And the result look like

```
nbr date        k   f(k)        f1_f(k)     d_k   tmpw       w
10  2019-02-19  100 0.000000    0.009679    5.0   0.001936   0.001936
11  2019-02-19  105 0.009679    0.037519    5.0   0.005568   0.003632
12  2019-02-19  110 0.037519    0.081904    5.0   0.008877   0.003309
13  2019-02-19  115 0.081904    0.141428    5.0   ...    
14  2019-02-19  120 0.141428    0.214852    5.0   ...
15  2019-02-19  125 0.214852    0.301086    5.0 
16  2019-02-19  130 0.301086    0.399163    5.0
```

Question: could anyone help to derive a quick code (not mathematically) without using loop?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: w[n] = tmpw[n]-(w[0]+w[1]+...w[n-1])

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, for me all those notation were a bit confusing.

If I got what you want right, for every row you want to have an accumulated value of all previous rows. than the value of another column of this row would be calculated based on this accumulated value.

In this case I would prefer something, calculate an accumulated column first, use it later.

for example:
note you need to call list(range()) instead of list, so your example is throwing an error

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def f_ST(ST,F,T):
    a=ST/F-1-np.log(ST/F)
    return 2*a/T

df=pd.DataFrame(list(range(50,140,5)),columns=['K'])
df['f(K0)']=df.apply(lambda x: f_ST(x.K,100,0.25),axis=1)
df['f(K1)']=df['f(K0)'].shift(-1)
df['dK']=df['K'].diff(1)
df['accumulate'] = df['K'].shift(1).cumsum() 
df['currentVal-accumulated'] = df['K'] - df['accumulate'] 
print(df)
```

prints:

```
      K     f(K0)           ...            accumulate  currentVal-accumulated
0    50  1.545177           ...                   NaN                     NaN
1    55  1.182696           ...                  50.0                     5.0
2    60  0.886605           ...                 105.0                   -45.0
3    65  0.646263           ...                 165.0                  -100.0
4    70  0.453400           ...                 230.0                  -160.0
5    75  0.301457           ...                 300.0                  -225.0
6    80  0.185148           ...                 375.0                  -295.0
7    85  0.100151           ...                 455.0                  -370.0
8    90  0.042884           ...                 540.0                  -450.0
9    95  0.010346           ...                 630.0                  -535.0
10  100  0.000000           ...                 725.0                  -625.0
11  105  0.009679           ...                 825.0                  -720.0
12  110  0.037519           ...                 930.0                  -820.0
13  115  0.081904           ...                1040.0                  -925.0
14  120  0.141428           ...                1155.0                 -1035.0
15  125  0.214852           ...                1275.0                 -1150.0
16  130  0.301086           ...                1400.0                 -1270.0
17  135  0.399163           ...                1530.0                 -1395.0

[18 rows x 6 columns]
```